# How to transpose link using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Lets say I have a row on one sheet:

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
```

I want to copy, transpose and paste links to those cells to another sheet in Excel like so:

```
=Sheet2!A1
=Sheet2!B1
=Sheet2!C1
=Sheet2!D1
=Sheet2!E1
```

Is there a way to do this with VBA? For some reason this code does not work and all I get is

```
=Sheet2!A1 
=Sheet2!A2
```

etc.

```
Sub Pastelinks()
Worksheets("Data_All_01").Range("$D$23:$AG$23").Copy
With Worksheets("DB 1,5€").Range("$F$287")
    .PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    .Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't that what transpose is supposed to do? Take a row and "rotate" it into a column? If that's not what you want, just leave out the `Transpose:=True`-Part.

Comment: If I don't transpose it then it will just paste the links horizontally (even though it will paste them correctly, keeping the column names). I want to copy the links and paste them vertically.

Comment: You wrote that you want to paste the cell values from `A1 B1 C1...` to `Sheet2!A1 Sheet2!B1 Sheet2!C1...` - I can't see where you want to rotate anything here :/ Are you maybe talking about text orientation inside one cell?

Comment: Not the values, the links to these cells. If I don't transpose then it will paste them horizontally in Sheet1 in cells A1, B1, C1, D1 etc, but I would like for them to be pasted in Sheet1 in cells A1,A2,A3, A4 etc.

Comment: Oook. So the problem right now is that the _target_ of the links is transposed, instead of the _position_ of the links?

Comment: If I copy the links to cells A1, B1, C1 in Sheet2 and try to paste them in Sheet1, they will be pasted as =Sheet2!A1, =Sheet2!B1, =Sheet2!C1 in cells A1, B1, C1. If I try to transpose while pasting, it will paste =Sheet2!A1, =Sheet2!A2, =Sheet2!A3 into cells A1, A2, A3. What I would like to do is for it to paste =Sheet2!A1, =Sheet2!B1, =Sheet2!C1 into cells A1, A2, A3. Hope this is more clear now, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I suggest you don't copy, but directly write the links into the target cells. Use a variable for that, and leave out the `.Activate`. I think @Vityata's answer gives a good start for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid copy/paste in vba

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Integer, ii As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("DB 1,5") 'insert euro character back

    '4 is column D
    '33 is column AG
    For i = 4 To 33
        ws.Cells(287 + ii, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=Data_All_01!R23C" & i
        ii = ii + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why should I avoid copy/paste?

Comment: it's slower than most other options

Answer (score 1):

This will take the values from the range A1:A4 of the opened worksheet and will put them in sheet(2), using the starting column and row of the initial range.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransposeMe()

    Dim my_cell         As Range
    Dim l_counter       As Long
    Dim l_row           As Long
    Dim l_col           As Long

    l_row = Range("A1:D1").Row
    l_col = Range("A1:D1").Column

    For Each my_cell In Range("A1:D1")
        Sheets(2).Cells(l_row, l_col) = my_cell
        l_row = l_row + 1
    Next my_cell

End Sub
```